# Powershell profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies

Tags: powershell

When starting a PowerShell host (powershell.exe, PowerShellISE, NuGet Package Manager Console etc) I was getting the following error message.

> File C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
>   cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software
>   restriction policies. For more information, contact your system
>   administrator.

This was particularly problematic in the case of the NuGet Package Manager Console as the console was left in a disabled / unusable state after the error. Other PowerShell hosts could at least be used.

I had problems a few weeks ago, when setting up my workstation at a new job, because a Group Policy setting was applying a *MachinePolicy* of *AllSigned*. That issue had been resolved by changing the setting to *RemoteSigned*. I checked that this setting is still in place using the command:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

I also confirmed that this **$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts** file exists but my Internet searches for another *"Group Policy setting"* revealed nothing of interest. My PowerShell version information is:

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18408
BuildVersion                   6.2.8370.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I **delete or move** the problem profile script then all of my PowerShell hosts start without errors, including the PowerShell ISE which was using it's own *Current User Current Host* script C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1

It turns out that the problem with my All Hosts profile script was that it was ***completely empty***! Adding any content into the file, even a single space character or comment, allowed this profile script to be *executed* by all of the various PowerShell hosts. I must have cleared out the contents of this script at some point, instead of deleting it.

Not exactly an intuitive error message which is why I'm posting this Q&A style entry for future reference.

Interestingly, I am able to *execute* empty / blank scripts in all hosts after they have started and this problem seems to be specific to profile scripts.

Comment: Actually, attempting to run an empty file like `powershell empty.ps1` causes same error message! When I simply added a single `#` character to the file, the error went away. Looks like this is simply a misleading error message.

Answer (score 5):

Delete both files

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
```

Comment: This solved my problem instantly.

Answer (score 3):

I want to use the defualt profile, but I got a same question.

I have changed the executionplicy to solve the problem.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

[link]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that looks like AppLocker error message. Some information about it can be found [here](http://jamessql.blogspot.nl/2013/04/limit-running-powershell-script-under.html) (however author is doing reverse - he tries to limit script usage).

If other profiles work (other than profile.ps1) that it may be just a deny rule.

Comment: Perhaps my answer is not clear but the problem goes away when I add any content to the profile. In other words I have a solution and my Q&A is to document the solution. For your information, other profiles exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: Out of curiosity (I haven't heard about AppLocker before) I checked my system and confirmed that there are no Script Rules configured for my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

Then reboot your PC.

[image: Final Result]